# not allowing null values a a data bound (This constraint cannot be enabled as not all values have corresponding parent values)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, telerik

**i am getting this error**
"This constraint cannot be enabled as not all values have corresponding parent values."
**from below code**

```
DataTable dt = objBLOrgSpecialityManager.getSpecialityTreeChild(UserId);
rdtrvwServices.DataSource = dt;
rdtrvwServices.DataFieldID = "NodeId";
rdtrvwServices.DataFieldParentID = "ParentId";
rdtrvwServices.DataTextField = "NodeName";
rdtrvwServices.DataValueField = "NodeId";
rdtrvwServices.DataBind();
```

Comment: **dataTable contains**
NodeId===========NodeName=====ParentId=======Status=====NodeStatus====AppendName
1300000168=======Hotels=======2000000014-1=====-1=======1=============Hotel
1300000168-1=====Rating=======1300000168=======1========11 
1300000168-16====Services=====1300000168=======1========11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every row does'nt contains parentID one must be null (the root node)